# Stop the audio when other is clicked

Tags: java, android, audio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Media Player Loops

    //Loops
    MediaPlayer dk1;
    MediaPlayer dk2;   

    //Mediaplayer Location
    dk1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dholak01);
    dk2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dholak03);
}



//Looping and start Media Player

public void playdk1 (View view) {
    if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
        return;
    }

    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
    } else {
        dk1.start();
        dk1.setLooping(true);
    }
}

public void playdk2 (View view) {
    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
        return;
    }

    if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
    } else {
        dk2.start();
        dk2.setLooping(true);
    }
}
```

There are two buttons in my UI ...These two buttons have two audio separately , I have mentioned it as dk1 and dk2. I want

1.To stop dk1 when dk2 is pressed

2.To repeat the procedure all time

3.I want to create another 6 audio like above dk1 and dk2

PROBLEM:
   I CANT PLAY LIKE THIS MORE THAT 1 TIME

PLEASE HELP ME....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are some mistakes in your code because the two methods are the same. I assume they are two different method: `playdk1` and `playdk2` which plays a different audio.

Version1: When the button is clicked, the audio is stopped and another audio is played.

```
public void playdk1 (View view) {
    if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
        dk1.reset();

        return;
    }

    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
        dk2.reset();
    }

    dk1.start();
    dk1.setLooping(true);
}

public void playdk2 (View view) {
    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
        dk2.reset();

        return;
    }

    if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
        dk1.reset();
    }

    dk2.start();
    dk2.setLooping(true);
}
```

Version 2: When the button is clicked, the audio is stopped. When the button is clicked the second time, another audio is played.

```
public void playdk1 (View view) {
    if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
        dk1.reset();            

        return;
    }

    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
        dk2.reset();
    } else {
        dk1.start();
        dk1.setLooping(true);
    }
}

public void playdk2 (View view) {
    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
        dk2.reset();

        return;
    }

    if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
        dk1.reset();
    } else {
        dk2.start();
        dk2.setLooping(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are two audio

Comment: Ok so my assumption is correct. There are two versions of the code. You use the one that suits your situation.

Comment: wwhat should I do

Comment: I improved my answer. You can try it and see if it works now.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `return`.

Comment: I can't repeat the function more than one time ....can you please suggest me to repeat the function all the time

Comment: Please tell me what is the class of dk1 and dk2.

Comment: can u send your mail ID

Comment: Can you try `prepare()` instead of `start()`?

Comment: unhandled exception

Comment: I HAVE EDITED THE QUESTION

Comment: You can follow this tutorial article and learn how to use `MediaPlayer` API: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html.

Answer (score 1):

use stop() method

```
  public void playdk2 (View view) {
    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
    } else {
        dk2.start();
        dk2.setLooping(true);
    }
```

Comment: If i'm playing audio 1 and suddenly clicked on audio 2 ...they both will play...and when i click on audio 1 and stopped it,I can't play another time...please

Comment: changing only stop(); will stop the whole music and won't play that music at that time...so I used pause();

Comment: Use can use Service to start and Stop music.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void clickFirst(View view)
{
   if(firstMedia.isPlaying())
   {
   firstMedia.stop();
   secondMedia.start();
   secondMedia.setLooping(true);
   }
   else
   {
     firstMedia.start();
     firstMedia.setLooping(true);
     secondMedia.stop();
   }

}

public void clickSecond(View view)
{
   if(secondMedia.isPlaying())
   {
   secondMedia.stop();
   firstMedia.start();
   firstMedia.setLooping(true);
   }

   else
   {
     secondMedia.start();
     secondMedia.setLooping(true);
     firstMedia.stop();
   }
}
```

Comment: where can I add looping

Comment: @JobyReuben see now

Comment: but when I play first media I can't play second media and whwn i play first media i can't play second media